# PCRE Regexp - Match just for one pair of square brackets

Tags: regex, pcre

Match only if there is a single pair of square brackets using PCRE regexp engine. Tried `.+\[[^\[\]]*\]` but still matches `array[[]`.

Examples for better understanding:

**Good**

```
array[]
array[1]
array[associative]
```

**Bad**

```
array[[]
array[]]
array[[]]
array[[1]
array[onther array[1]]
```

Comment: is `][` supposed to be bad ?

Comment: Did [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60057737/3832970) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.` if you want it to not match `[` or `]`.

It's not clear what exactly you want but the literal answer to your question is

```
\[[^][]*\]
```

which matches a literal opening square bracket `\[`, a character class which matches any character which is not `]` or `[`, repeated zero or more times, and a literal closing square bracket `\]`.

The character class `[^][]` can look a bit mind-boggling until you realize that the `]` has to come before the `[` in the enumeration of characters in the negated character class.

Some regex tools also allow `\]` in a character class but this is not universal or portable. In some others it means a literal backslash and the end of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matches `array[[]` because `.+\[` first matches any character *(including the first `[`)* until the end of the line  and then backtracks until the last occurrence of `[` where the rest of the pattern will then match until the first closing `]`

If there can be only a single opening square bracket followed by a single closing square bracket on the same line, you might make use of negated character classed `[^[\]\r\n]` matching any character except the listed:

```
^[^[\]\r\n]+\[[^[\]\r\n]*]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iFU7hf/1)

Or without anchors you could use a negative lookahead `(?![[\]])` to make sure there is not square bracket following

```
[^[\]\r\n]+\[[^[\]\r\n]*\](?![[\]])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SMOC0Z/1)

Note that this pattern works for the current example data, but is can be eligible for many failing edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

A regex to match  a string that only has one single pair of `[...]` use

```
^[^][]*\[[^][]*][^][]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/agu1Sl/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\[` - `[`
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a  `]` char
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `$` - end of string.